# Looking for a Standard Data Interchange Format

Tags: integration, standards

We are going to be moving some data around that will have some standard fields as well as some key value pairs which will vary between data items. Obviously we could code something in JSON or XML to do this and write our own marshalling/unmarshalling code however I was hoping for a standards based solution that has some or all of the following:

- Marshalling/unmarshalling for SharePoint lists/.Net
- Marshalling/unmarshalling for Java
- Service definitions and semantics for operating on the data across an integration boundary
- Security semantics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are currently looking at the OData protocol to perform this task: http://www.odata.org/

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you've made your decision long ago now, but for anyone else who ends up here, and is perhaps interested in something at a lower level than OData, here's what I'm using for C# to Java data interchange:

Google Protocol buffers as the interchange format:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Marc Gravell's protobuf-net at the C# end:
http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

A program called called protostuff at the Java end:
http://code.google.com/p/protostuff/

(I prefer protostuff to the official Google Java implementation of protocol buffers due to Google's implementation being based on the Java objects being immutable.)

Actually, I'm not using pure protocol buffers as the interchange format - I prefix the data with the name of the (outermost) class being transmitted. This makes the data self-identifying for deserializing at the other end.